# Numbers separated by spaces in txt file into python list

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a txt file containing lines of numbers separated by spaces into numbers separated by commas in lists, where each line is a new list of these numbers using Python 3.

E.g. txt file contains

> 1  2  3  4  5
>
> 6  7  8  9  10

and I want this in python:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]

[6,7,8,9,10]
```

I can't seem to find a good solution, I used numpy and obtained the list of lists but not comma separated, e.g.:
`[[1  2  3  4  5],[6  7  8  9 10]]`

Here is the example code I've used that doesn't quite work:

```
import numpy as np

mymatrix = np.loadtxt('file')
```

Grateful for any input! (ps I'm a beginner but want to use the lists in a programme I am developing)

Answer (score 0):

Following uses plain Python 3 (without NumPy)

```
# open file
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    # 1. iterate over file line-by-line
    # 2. strip line of newline symbols
    # 3. split line by spaces into list (of number strings)
    # 4. convert number substrings to int values
    # 5. convert map object to list
    data = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(' '))) for line in fp]
```

This provides the result you're looking for:

```
>>> with open('data.txt') as fp:
...     data = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(' '))) for line in fp]
... 
>>> print(data)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your numpy code works just fine, and you're just not used to the way it formats arrays for display.

Maybe this will give results more like you were expecting:

```
import numpy as np

mymatrix = np.loadtxt('file')
print (np.array_repr(mymatrix))
```